# Recreating HTTP Trigger Using Previously Downloaded Source Code

Tags: node.js

I created an HTTP trigger, downloaded the source code, deleted the HTTP trigger and tried recreating a new HTTP trigger using the source code. I got an error message.
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5o1e.png)

Comment: Your question is very unclear, you downloaded some code from where ?, what do you want to achieve?, also please show some code explaining what you have done so far.

Comment: I downloaded the code from the Google Cloud Platform. I want to create a new HTTP Trigger using the source code I downloaded.